# What do elements of the first homology group mean topologically?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

By Hurewicz theorem we know that $H_1(X)$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$. Let $X = S_1 \vee S_1$. Mark the the loops ($S_1$) by $a$ and $b$. Then $\pi_1(X) = \langle a,b\mid \;\rangle$ which is a free non-abelian group. After abelianization, $H_1(X) = \langle a,b\mid a+b=b+a\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $F:\pi_1(X) \to H_1(X)$ be a functor, then for example:

$F \circ \pi_1(abaa) = F \circ \pi_1(aaab) = \cdots = H_1(X) = 3a + b$.
Put a point $A$ inside the loop $a$, then winding number of $abaa$ and $aaab$ at $A$ is $3$ which is in fact a coefficient of $a$ in $H_1(X)$. Hence we could think of an element of $H_1(X)$ as a vector of winding numbers of the mapped loop with respect to the points inside the generating loops (i.e. $a$, $b$).

However, this notion seems to me rather artificial and I do not know what this vector actually means, how it can be used. How do you think of elements of $H_1(X)$?

Comment: A small observation (not really an answer):  When we know that a group is abelian (as in $H^1(X)$), we tend to denote the group operation additively, hence expressions such as $3a + b$.  But, in the context of this theorem, it may be nice to write the relation multiplicatively, so $abaa$ and $aaab$ both map to $a^3b$.

Comment: A LaTeX tip: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for *that meaning only*. When you want angle brackets, you need to use `\langle` and `\rangle`. Though it seems like you're already somewhat familiar with TeX, you may still the advice [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) helpful. [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is also very useful.

Comment: @ZevChonoles : I see you just reached 50k! Congrats.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed do not know latex well and a good reference is useful.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon: Thanks - and congrats on Brown!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morally, $H_1$ is the abelian free group on cycles, that is, closed curves in the space, modulo the relation of homology: two cycles $a$ and $b$ are homologous if there is an oriented surface in the space whose boundary is $a-b$.

For example, if $a$ is a generator of $H_1(P_{\mathbb R}^1)$ then $2a=0$. This means that there is no surface in the projective plave such that its boundary is the curve $a$, but there is one whose boundary is $a+a$. Probably you know how to exhibit a map $D\to H_1(P_{\mathbb R}^1)$ from the closed disk to the projective place such that the restriction to the boundary of $D$ is twice the generator.

That $a\neq0$, on the other hand, implies that there is no map $D\to P_{\mathbb R}^1$ whose restriction to the boundary is $a$. But this is even more true than that:  there is no surface $\Sigma$ with boundary a circle such that there is a map $\Sigma\to P_{\mathbb R}^1$ whose restriction to the boundary is $a$.